# Icons of the Applications still remains there even after uninstallation

Tags: icons, uninstall

I have recently deleted many of my applications in my UBUNTU. But even after Deletion the Icons are still there in the Dock. I clicked on them but they didn't opened, meaning they are removed but their icons didn't.
What should I do Now????

Answer (score 2):

There may be .desktop files for your removed applications in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`.  They're used to populate the Dock.